# using rand() in a function in c

Tags: c, random

I have made a function that creates a random number between 0 and 9 but when i call the function in main in a for loop with index i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ it prints 1 random number n types. but i want different values to be printed n times. 
here is the code which i made :-

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    void random_variable() {
     int i;
     srand(time(NULL));
     i = rand()%10;
     printf("%d ",i);
    }
    main() {
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
      random_variable();
     }
    }
```

output is this :-

please click on the link to see the output :-
[here instead of 8 ten times i needed 10 different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWhvT.png)

Comment: Don't redo the `srand` inside the loop - do it once before looping. It'll cause it to get reseeded and because it can loop 10 times so quickly, it'll get reseeded to the same value each time. I won't get into the deficiencies of `rand` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`srand()` initializes the PRNG (pseudo random number generator) of your standard C library. A PRNG works by applying more-or-less complicated arithmetic operations to a value stored internally and returning part of the result as the next "random" number. `srand()` sets this internal state.

If you call `srand()` every time in your function, you won't get (sensible) random numbers because the internal state is reset every time. Call it once your program starts.

Comment: okk. if i am using rand() two times to create two different sets of random number then also i have to use  srand() once?

Comment: @NehalBirla I thought I explained this ...

Answer (score 2):

`srand()` seeds your random numbers. You want to do this once, not every time.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    void random_variable() {
       int i;
       i = rand()%10;
       printf("%d ",i);
    }
    main() {
       srand(time(NULL));
       for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
          random_variable();
       }
    }
```

Comment: if i use rand() two times i the function to create two different sets of random numbers then also i have to use srand() only once

Comment: Yes. Almost always, you want to call srand() ONCE per program.